# How to Combine two array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two array in my applications, in this case i want to combine two array in my application but  i tried  and failed.. here is my code.. please combine array data and data2 :

```
Data[] data = {
        new Data(-79.400917f,43.661049f, "New New College Res",
                "Residence building (new concrete high-rise)", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),
        new Data(-79.394524f,43.655796f, "Baldwin Street",
                "Here be many good restaurants!", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),
        new Data(-79.402206f,43.657688f, "College St",
                "Lots of discount computer stores if you forgot a cable or need to buy hardware.", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),    
        new Data(-79.390381f,43.659878f, "Queens Park Subway",
                "Quickest way to the north-south (Yonge-University-Spadina) subway/metro line", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),

};

Data[] data2 = {
        new Data(-79.403732f,43.666801f, "Spadina Subway",
                "Quickest way to the east-west (Bloor-Danforth) subway/metro line", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),
        new Data(-79.399696f,43.667873f, "St George Subway back door",
                "Token-only admittance, else use Spadina or Bedford entrances!", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),
        new Data(-79.384163f,43.655083f, "Eaton Centre (megamall)",
                "One of the largest indoor shopping centres in eastern Canada. Runs from Dundas to Queen.", "R.drawable.mr_kun"),
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Data[] mergedArray = new Data[data.length + data2.length];
System.arraycopy(data, 0, mergedArray, 0, data.length);
System.arraycopy(data2, 0, mergedArray, data.length, data2.length);
```

Comment: +1 Nice finding... this seems to be work..

Comment: I din't ask this question... and I am sure if OP finds this answer worked for him he will accept your answer.. :)

Comment: Iam sorry but not work..

Comment: please help me friend..

Answer (score 5):

First convert your `String array` to `List` than use `addAll` metod to add `List`

**Example**

```
ArrayList<String> first;
ArrayList<String> second;
second.addAll(first);
```

Comment: i have tried but error .. my type array is Data not string.. please give me help..

Comment: that is why he wrote "FIRST convert String array to List :-)

Comment: give me any other solution..??

Comment: (ﾉಥ益ಥ）ﾉ he gave you the solution.

Comment: and where is OP's String array? I think he is using array of Objects.. right? And how he can convert array of object into array of String... do you have any clue?

Comment: Yes convert object array to simple array or directly to arrayList

Comment: why converting Data to string? why not set type of list to Data? this is not REAL solution

Comment: yeah can you give me other answer..?

Answer (score 0):

You can easly use Apache Commons Lang library.
Then your code will look:

```
ArrayUtils.addAll(data, data2);
```

Here is documetation for this method:
[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object[])](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: help me guys.. not work..